# make applescript auto-click

Tags: macos, click, applescript

I play a game in Safari.

I want to make an applescript that auto clicks for me in a special spot on the screen, I have tried many things but none of it has worked for me.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can record the mouse movement with Automator and play this record: you can save it as application, too...
It's the easiest way, in my opinion...

Answer (score 3):

```
delay 3
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "TheApp"
        key code 53
        delay 1
        click (click at {1800, 1200})
    end tell
end tell
```

However, it doesn't seem to work in Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

```
repeat 10 times
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Safari"
            click (click at {650, 730})
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

should work for you

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to achieve the same thing as you a few months/years ago :)

I was botting(the thing you want to achieve) a game named Runescape =P

Of course it is against the rule so you may get banned :S

As sylter says you can use Automator to automate your task (which is the only solution) i tried to click the mouse button but i was not able to find out how :/

you should use automator! it is REALLY easy :)